# convert Soap XML into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a soap request and, I need to convert soap xml to a php array. but I am stuck in a position where I can't figure out how to set attributes to array properly. I am very new to soap and good explanation will be appreciated. Here is what I have done so far.

what i want to create

```
<arg0>
    <ns2:coverType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="ns2:FamilyCoverType">
        <ns2:abc>1978-04-03</ns2:abc>
        <ns2:def>1980-04-03</ns2:def>
        <ns2:pqr>2016-04-10</ns2:pqr>
        <ns2:xyz>2016-05-03</ns2:xyz>
    </ns2:coverType>
</arg0>
```

My array

```
$data = array(
        'arg0' => array(
            'coverType' => array(
                'abc' => $abc,
                'def' => $def,
                'pqr' => $pqr,
                'xyz' => $xyz,
            )
        )
    );
```

Everything is fine except

> xsi:type="ns2:FamilyCoverType"

How can I set above attribute in my array?? Pls Help.

Comment: Do you have a WSDL URL you can add to the question?

Comment: @KrisPeeling I'm sorry. I cannot share since it is sensitive information.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are asking how to convert XML to PHP array? or array to XML?

Comment: I'm converting PHP array to SOAP XML.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) as you won't wonder at all how to structure your request. If you use Eclipse PDT or any other good IDE with the generated PHP SDK, you'll send the requests in a few seconds. Moreover, you'll handle very easily the response as you'll have known PHP objects as they would have been generated as PHP classes within the SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I'll work on that.

Answer (score 1):

After two hectic weeks I could finally came to a solution. So I'm posting my answer here so someone could save his time.

we can do above thing like this easily,

```
$param = new \SoapVar('
           <arg0>
               <ns2:coverType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:FamilyCoverType">
                   <ns2:abc>' . $data['abc'] . '</ns2:abc>
                    <ns2:def>' . $data['def'] . '</ns2:def>
                    <ns2:pqr>' . $data['pqr'] . '</ns2:pqr>
                    <ns2:xyz>' . $data['xyz'] . '</ns2:xyz>
               </ns2:coverType>
           </arg0>', XSD_ANYXML);
```

Then we can get the response like this,

```
$response = $client->your_calling_function($param);
```

As far as it seems,

> XSD_ANYXML

is the key.

If someone still having trouble with that I am really happy to help. do not hesitate to ask for help.